# OSX won't boot after installing Windows 8 with bootcamp

Tags: macos, windows-8

I've just install Windows 8 on my iMac using bootcamp and now when I restart my machine Windows 8 starts but there doesn't seem to be an obvious way of starting OSX again.

Is there a keyboard key I need to hold down during start up that will allow me to boot back into OSX?

Comment: Part of the problem is that Windows 8 is not officially supported by Boot Camp at this time: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1899 of course how to install and use Windows 8 through Boot Camp is well documented: http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/11/no-support-no-problem-installing-windows-8-on-a-mac-with-boot-camp/

Answer (score 2):

All one has to do is tell Windows 8 to restart and then hold down the Option key. On restarting, this will bring up a boot OS menu which allows one to select the OSX boot drive.

Comment: Note that it still possible that Windows installation broke your OSX boot partition. In that case you simply need to boot on a restoration partition or on an OSX DVD and do a disk verification/reparation. It will update your boot partition and restore OSX boot.